# Calculating percent change over time with a longitudal dataset

Tags: r, time-series, data-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the year to year change in some data I have. It is in panel/longitudinal form

the data is in a dataframe that looks like this

```
Year    ZipCode     Value
2011    11411         5
2012    11411         10
2013    11411         20
2011    11345         6
2012    11345         7 
2013    11345         10
```

I would like to get a dataframe that comes out in the form like this

```
Year Differnce    Zipcode    % Change
2011-2012         11411        100%
2012-2013         11411        100%
2011-2012         11345        16%
2012-2013         11345        42%
```

Comment: This was a good question, why was it edited to make the input and output not correspond?

Comment: Sorr, that was a mistake. Rolled back

Answer (score 2):

One way would using `dplyr` is to calculate `Change` by subtracting current `Value` from previous `Value` and `paste` the `Year` together for each `ZipCode`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ZipCode) %>%
  mutate(Change = (Value - lag(Value))/lag(Value) * 100, 
         Year_Diff = paste(lag(Year), Year, sep = "-")) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  select(Year_Diff, ZipCode, Change)

#  Year_Diff ZipCode Change
#  <chr>       <int>  <dbl>
#1 2011-2012   11345   16.7
#2 2012-2013   11345   42.9
#3 2011-2012   11411  100  
#4 2012-2013   11411  100
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, we group by 'ZipCode', take the `diff` of 'Value', divide by the'Value' length adjusted while `paste`ing the adjacent 'Year' together

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Change  = 100 *diff(Value)/Value[-.N], 
    Year_Diff = paste(Year[-.N], Year[-1], sep="-")),  .(ZipCode)]
#    ZipCode    Change Year_Diff
#1:   11411 100.00000 2011-2012
#2:   11411 100.00000 2012-2013
#3:   11345  16.66667 2011-2012
#4:   11345  42.85714 2012-2013
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L
), ZipCode = c(11411L, 11411L, 11411L, 11345L, 11345L, 11345L
), Value = c(5L, 10L, 20L, 6L, 7L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```